# Finding prime numbers in a input list in Python

Tags: python, list, numbers

I am new to Python. The results from my codes are weird, results are not shown up. How to write the code using While statement?

```
#Primenumber
A=[int(x) for x in input().split(",")]
B=[]

for element in A:
    i=2
    while (element%i)!=0:
        if (i<(element-1)):
            i=i+1
        else:
            B+=[element]
print(B)
```

I tried to write my codes using While Loop statement to determine prime number in an input list, but after tons of hard work, I even can not figure out myself. I have already had another solution by using variable t counting from 1 whenever element%count==0, if at the end t==1: the number was a prime number. However, I would like to find a new way/ new solution.

Comment: When do you expect the `while` loop to terminate? Are you sure that will happen?

Comment: I am not sure, I'm just new to it. I am just doing this way or that way to have answer for my curiosity. Sometimes it messed up that I have to spend like a day just to find another solution.

Comment: just wanted to know what is the range of an element in `A[i]..    0<=A[i]<=?` than the code can be generate in that way.. @Stevendo

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean, I input the array with all the elements at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to use `break` statement as when I ran your code the while loop was continuing forever. You will have to break `while` loop at a point. And in our case the point is when `i = element`

The code must be:

```
#Primenumber
A=[int(x) for x in input().split(",")]
B=[]

for element in A:
    i=2
    while (element%i)!=0:
        if (i<(element-1)):
            i=i+1
        else:
            B+=[element]
            break
print(B)
```

Tip: While trying out new thing it is better to print the way your loop runs in following way:

```
#Primenumber
A=[int(x) for x in input().split(",")]
B=[]

for element in A:
    i=2
    while (element%i)!=0:
        print("i: ", i) #Prints i values
        print("B: ", B) #Prints B values
        if (i<(element-1)):
            i=i+1
        else:
            B+=[element]
            break
print(B)
```